# Custom error pages are not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, apache, internet-explorer

I have a website with custom error pages linking back to index.

For example

```
http://example.com/123
```

is not an actual file but my PHP index will tell to make a dynamic page with ID 123

It works in all browsers except Internet Explorer, not sure why because this should be an apache setting.

It is just for nicer URLs.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache in IE?

Comment: in a case like this i will think its more of a cache problem. clear it and try again.

Comment: I also hope for SEO purposes you are forwarding the correct header on a bad result, so if ID '123' doesn't exist and triggers this error page, you should be sending a 404 and a re-direct to a standard error page. Else, it looks like '123' does exist, and you may have hundreds of pages of duplicated content across your site. That won't look good to Google.

Comment: @Markus: Surely you don't mean "sending a 404 _and_ a re-direct". That would be impossible. A redirect would imply a 301 or 302. Maybe you meant "sending a 404 and a link"?

Comment: @Asaph you're right - I meant to say print out the file he's redirecting too :)

Comment: Through PHP How can I send a header  that will tell IE and Google that a page exists?

Answer (score 1):

Is your error page less than 512 bytes? Some versions of [Internet Explorer show the stock "friendly" error page if the size is less than 512 bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404#Custom_error_pages). Additionally, there is a setting within Internet Explorer options that turns the "friendly" error pages on and off.

Comment: It is more than 512 bytes. But how will visitors know to change a setting. Is there an alternative way?